# Faster or smarter way to sort and intersect large amount of data?

Tags: matlab, sorting, intersect

I was using "intersect" in my Matlab code to do the sorting where I want the following:

```
[ch] = sort(s, 'ascend'); 

[same, a] = intersect(s, ch);
```

For example:

input:

```
s = [55 21 78 7]
```

output:

```
ch = [7 21 55 78]
a = [4 2 1 3]
```

I need to access `a` where `a` shows the original index prior to sorting so I can use it for further processing.

This method works exactly as what I want, but I guess it is taking a lot of time to do the sorting and intersect etc especially when the size of `s` approaching 100 or higher, are there faster or smarter ways to do so?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with

```
[ch IX] = sort(s, 'ascend')
```

where `IX` is identical to `a`.